# GStreamer Video Analytics Plugin

Tags: gstreamer

I am attempting to write a GStreamer wrapper around a video analytic library. The input is video frames and the output is a metadata object. The metadata object contains the binary representation of the outlines of the objects in the video. This will be used downstream as to further inspect the metadata.

- Is the `GstBaseTransform` the correct parent class for this conversion? Or should I be using some `GstVideo*` base class? Like `GstVideoFilterClass`?
- Should the plugin type be `Converter/Video/Metadata`?

It seems that the `GstBaseTransform` is more set up for filters. Should I just derive from `GstElement`? I can't really find an example of this in any prior plugins.

The node graph will sort of be like the following:

```
          video                    video                         video
VideoSrc ------- tee ------------------------------- Annotation ------- Stream
                  |                                       |
                  | video                        metadata |
                  |               metadata                |  metadata
                  `--- Analytics ---------- Processing ---'------------ Cloud
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `GstVideoFilterClass` and the `GstMeta` API to implement this rather than split up the streams.